# Java - Salesforce PartnerConnection Query request hangs

Tags: java, salesforce, apex

I have a written a simple program to test Java to Salesforce integration. I followed the steps mentioned in the links below:

[Salesforce Api Partner Examples](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_partner_examples.htm)

[Sample Query Calls](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sample_query_calls.htm#topic-title)

But when I execute these, the program hangs at the step

`QueryResult qr = partnerConnection.query(soqlQuery);`

I'm not sure what is happening here - any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an outdated version of the SDK and running against a new endpoint, your program will hang.

To fix this, use the latest version of the SDK as well as point to the latest endpoint.

For example, I used:

```
/services/Soap/u/34.0
```

as the endpoint and the following projects versions in maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>force-wsc</artifactId>
  <version>34.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>force-partner-api</artifactId>
  <version>34.0</version>
</dependency>
```